# ellipse midpoint algorithm counterclockwise version

Tags: algorithm, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to convert the standart clockwise ellipse midpoint algorithm taken from the book "Computer Graphics with OpenGL" so that it would work counter-clockwise starting from region 2.
I got it to work and draw an ellipse but its not identical to the one the original algorithm draws so I assume I have a small bug in my code which I can't seem to find, can some please help?

This is the original algorithm:

```
void ellipseMidpoint(int xCenter, int yCenter, int Rx, int Ry)
{
    int Rx2 = Rx * Rx;
    int Ry2 = Ry * Ry;
    int twoRx2 = 2 * Rx2;
    int twoRy2 = 2 * Ry2;
    int p;
    int x = 0;
    int y = Ry;
    int px = 0;
    int py = twoRx2 * y;
    void ellipsePlotPoints(int, int, int, int);

    /* Plot the initial point in each quadrant. */
    ellipsePlotPoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y);

    /* Region 1 */
    p = round(Ry2 - (Rx2 * Ry) + (0.25 * Rx2));
    while (px < py) {
        x++;
        px += twoRy2;
        if (p < 0)
            p += Ry2 + px;
        else {
            y--;
            py -= twoRx2;
            p += Ry2 + px - py;
        }
        ellipsePlotPoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y);
    }

    /* Region 2 */
    p = round(Ry2 * (x + 0.5) * (x + 0.5) + Rx2 * (y - 1) * (y - 1) - Rx2 * Ry2);
    while (y > 0) {
        y--;
        py -= twoRx2;
        if (p > 0)
            p += Rx2 - py;
        else {
            x++;
            px += twoRy2;
            p += Rx2 - py + px;
        }
        ellipsePlotPoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y);
    }
}

void ellipsePlotPoints(int xCenter, int yCenter, int x, int y)
{
    setPixel(xCenter + x, yCenter + y);
    setPixel(xCenter - x, yCenter + y);
    setPixel(xCenter + x, yCenter - y);
    setPixel(xCenter - x, yCenter - y);
}
```

and this is my version:

```
void ellipseMidpointCounterClockwise(int xCenter, int yCenter, int Rx, int Ry)
{
    int Rx2 = Rx * Rx;
    int Ry2 = Ry * Ry;
    int twoRx2 = 2 * Rx2;
    int twoRy2 = 2 * Ry2;
    int p;
    int x = Rx;
    int y = 0;
    int px = twoRy2 * x;
    int py = 0;
    void ellipsePlotPoints(int, int, int, int);

    /* Plot the initial point in each quadrant. */
    ellipsePlotPoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y);

    /* Region 2 */
    p = round(Ry2 * (x - 0.5) * (x - 0.5) + Rx2 * (y + 1) * (y + 1) - Rx2 * Ry2);
    while (py < px) {
        y++;
        py += twoRx2;
        if (p > 0)
            p += Rx2 - py;
        else {
            x--;
            px -= twoRy2;
            p += Rx2 - py + px;
        }
        ellipsePlotPoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y);
    }

    /* Region 1 */

    p = round(Ry2 * (x - 1.0) * (x - 1.0) + Rx2 * (y + 0.5) * (y + 0.5) - Rx2 * Ry2);
    while (x > 0) {
        x--;
        px -= twoRy2;
        if (p < 0)
            p += Ry2 + px;
        else {
            y++;
            py += twoRx2;
            p += Ry2 + px - py;
        }
        ellipsePlotPoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y);
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some helping finding what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that the original code is not symmetric with respect to x and y (and your ellipseMidpointCounterClockwise actually just replaces x and y).

ellipseMidpoint(0,0,3,2) generates for the first quadrant

```
0 2
1 2
2 1
3 0
```

whereas ellipseMidpoint(0,0,2,3) generates for the first quadrant

```
0 3
1 3
2 2
2 1
2 0
```

when exchanging coordinates and reversing the order we get:

```
0 2
1 2
2 2
3 1
3 0
```

Graphically this means:

```
002
| 12
+--0
```

where `+` denotes the center, `0` denotes ellipse points in both results, 1 a point only in the first result, 2 points only in the second result (mirrored).

If you want your ellipseMidpointCounterClockwise to generate exactly the same points you could - instead of replacing x and y - just go into the negative x-direction (i.e. x-- instead of x++ in the original code). Otherwise you have to live with the difference in symmetry.

The second problem is that you did not just replace x and y but also do some other strange replacements. If you just replace x and y within the regions you get the correct result:

```
void ellipseMidpointCounterClockwise(int xCenter, int yCenter, int Rx, int Ry)
{
  int Rx2 = Rx * Rx;
  int Ry2 = Ry * Ry;
  int twoRx2 = 2 * Rx2;
  int twoRy2 = 2 * Ry2;
  int p;
  int x = Rx;
  int y = 0;
  int px = twoRy2 * x;
  int py = 0;
  void ellipsePlotPoints(int, int, int, int);

  /* Plot the initial point in each quadrant. */
  ellipsePlotPoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y);

  /* Region 2 */
  p = round(Rx2 - (Ry2 * Rx) + (0.25 * Ry2));
  while (py < px) {
    y++;
    py += twoRx2;
    if (p < 0)
      p += Rx2 + py;
    else {
      x--;
      px -= twoRy2;
      p += Rx2 + py - px;
    }
    ellipsePlotPoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y);
  }

  /* Region 1 */
  p = round(Rx2 * (y + 0.5) * (y + 0.5) + Ry2 * (x - 1) * (x - 1) - Ry2 * Rx2);
  while (x > 0) {
    x--;
    px -= twoRy2;
    if (p > 0)
      p += Ry2 - px;
    else {
      y++;
      py += twoRx2;
      p += Ry2 - px + py;
    }
    ellipsePlotPoints(xCenter, yCenter, x, y);
  }
}
```

Comment: its not enough to just go in negative x direction because the requirment is that I start at position (rx,0) meaning I have to start at the second region and go with positive y and then get to region 1 and go in negative x. so you're saying that my algorithm is correct and it just produces different results?

Comment: I have not checked your algorithm - this you can now do yourself :-) If your algorithm is correct then ellipseMidpointCounterClockwise(0,0,Rx,Ry) will produce the same points as ellipseMidpoint(0,0,Ry,Rx) - except that x and y are exchanged.

Comment: No the damn thing is not the same and I can't figure out why

Comment: just rigourosly replace x and y. Are you here to steal other people's time?

Comment: what do you mean? I tried what you wrote in the last comment if it was the same then it would have produced the same ellipse only rotated 90 degrees, but it doesn't and I'm not sure whats wrong with my algorithm, I think maybe your answer was incorrect and I'm not trying to steal anyone's time, I'm just looking for help, I'm not forcing anyone to help me.

Comment: Nevermind, I saw that the second fix you did above solved it, it didn't look the same I think because of the width\height ratio of my window